# Calculating mean of sample in monte carlo simulation

Tags: python, performance, mean, montecarlo

I did a Monte Carlo simulation of n samples. For each sample i, I need to calculate the value Xi so probably, the results that I will obtain is:

> X = [X1, X2, ..., Xn]

(Here Xi can be a matrix or number).

Now I want to calculate the mean of theses samples that I call Xmean. So I need to obtain something like this:

> Xmean = [X1, (X1+X2)/2, (X1+X2+X3)/3 ... , (X1+X2+...+Xn)/n]

In Python, I write a code:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1):
         Xmean(i) = Xmean(i) + X(j)
    Xmean(i) = Xmean(i) / (i+1)
```

It works well but too slow, I would like to know if I can speed up this code? And if you guys could suggest to me some interesting Python's library that help for Monte Carlo simulation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit, numpy

setup = '''
from __main__ import mc0, mc1, mc2
import random, numpy

random.seed(0)
n = 10**3
data = [random.randint(0, 2**32-1) for _ in range(n)]
np_data = numpy.array([float(x) for x in data])
'''

# your implementation
def mc0(data):
    xmean = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        xmean.append(0)
        for j in range(i+1):
            xmean[i] += data[j]
        xmean[i] = xmean[i] / (i+1)
    return xmean

# my implementation
def mc1(data):
    xmean = []
    for i, x in enumerate(data):
        if i == 0:
            new = x
        else:
            new = x/(i+1) + xmean[i-1] * (i/(i+1))
        xmean.append(new)
    return xmean

# Donbeo's numpy implementation
def mc2(data):
    xmean = numpy.cumsum(data) / numpy.array(range(1, len(data)+1))
    return xmean


number = 100
things = [('mc0', 'mc0(data)'),
          ('mc1', 'mc1(data)'),
          ('mc2', 'mc2(np_data)')]
for note, call in things:
    print('{:20} {}'.format(note,
                            timeit.timeit(call, setup=setup, number=number)))
```

Result:

```
mc0                  26.023956370918587
mc1                  0.1423197092108488
mc2                  0.13584513496654083
```

There's no point in redoing the sum over `x(1)..x(i)` at each loop iteration, when you already have that information available in `xmean`. The numpy version by Donbeo is marginally faster than the pure-Python version by me, both of which are nearly 200 times faster (for these data, anyway) than the original version.

Answer (score 0):

By simply reducing the amount of calculation,

```
Xmean(0) = X(0)
for i in range(N-1):
    Xmean(i+1) = (Xmean(i)*(i+1) + X(i+1))/(i+2)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's faster for sure :D

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy it should be easy.

```
import numpy as np

X = [1,5,3,8,6,9]
Xmean = np.cumsum(X)
Xmean = Xmean/np.array(range(1,len(X)+1)
```

Comment: I think this is correct:
Xmean = Xmean/np.array(range(1, len(X)+1))